# Unable to concatenate multiple JSON files' data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the elements of several JSON files together into one array, however when printing `data`, it results in an empty array.

```js
let dataUrls = ["file1.json", "file2.json", "file3.json"];
let data = getData(dataUrls);
function getData(dataUrls) {
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataUrls.length; i++) {
        d3.json(dataUrls[i]).then(d => {
            data = data.concat(d);
        });
    }
    return data;
}
console.log(data)
```